# Published app on play-store, after few days get these errors in "Crashes& ANRs"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have never seen this error myself and have no idea how to reproduce it.
Could I please have some advice on this issue?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.domain.app/net.domain.app.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment net.domain.app.fragments.main.MainTabFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment net.domain.app.fragments.main.MainTabFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1790)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
at net.domain.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class net.domain.app.fragments.main.MainTabFragment; no empty constructor
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
... 18 more
```

It's related to :

```
net.domain.app.fragments.main.MainTabFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

This class never fails on any device I try, Class exists, is public and has public constructor

Line 104 in Main activity is ***super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);***:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Here is  [MainTabFragment](http://pastebin.com/9BB0usyr)

Comment: Please post the code to MainTabFragment. As you pointed out yourself, this is most likely where you have an error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Fragment has no empty constructor, which is what is causing the error :

> has an empty constructor that is public

You can overcome your problem by changing your constructor from this :

```
public MainTabFragment(LatteApplication _latte) {
    latte = _latte;
}
```

to this :

```
public MainTabFragment() {}
```

If you need to pass Objects to your Fragment when creating it, use a Bundle of arguments (your custom class LatteApplication needs to implement Parcelable or Serializable, here I'm giving you an example with Parcelable):

```
LatteApplication _latte;
//initialize that object

// Then do this when creating your Fragment
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("latte_application", _latte);
MainTabFragment fragment = new MainTabFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
//then add your Fragment to your layout.
```

Then in a Fragment method, for example in onActivityCreated, retrieve the arguments like this :

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if (args != null){
    LatteApplication _latte = args.getParcelable("latte_application");
}
```

You can check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to see what can be passed through a Bundle ...

Comment: Thank you, I missed that I need to have empty constructor. This will solve quite a few issues in my application.

Comment: Glad I could help. Wether you will make LatteApplication implement Parcelable/Serializable or pass only the relevant variables from that class to the Fragment using Bundle will mainly depend on the complexity/size of your LatteApplication class. Don't hesitate to ask if that's not clear for you ;)

Comment: LatteApplication is main placeholder for almost everything, all app/server events and most of everything is handled there. Fragments are quite new to me, one thing I don't understand jet is why I can't just pass it as setter after creating it? Thus leaving constructor empty.

Comment: It is better to keep your Fragment as independent as possible, try to give it only the objects needed for its instantiation in the Bundle. If you need global variables everywhere inside your app, you could extend the Application class or use a static singleton : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not wrong your LogCat is saying this "no empty constructor".

Basically, when subclass a fragment you need to **provide the empty constructor** if you aim to create different ones.

As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) says:

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state
>   restore.

Comment: Hmm, this is new to me. By empty constructor you mean no parameters and nothing inside it ?

Comment: I mean:
public MyFragment(){}